# Finding values in a columns "a" which has different values in column "b" for two different data set

Tags: r

Data contains multiple columns and 3000 row

Same `OrderNo` but different `Ordertype`.

I want to get all the `OrderNo` whose `Ordertype` are different in the two data frame.

I have isolated the two columns from the two data frame and set them in ascending order. Then I tried to use the function `cbind` to combine the two columns and find the missing values in one of the columns.

```
xxx <- data.frame( orderNo = c(1:10), Ordertype = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"))
yyy <- data.frame( orderNo = c(1:10), Ordertype = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "a", "b", "e", "d", "e", "f"))
```

In the above example: `OrderNo` "7" corresponds to "c" in one data frame and "e" in another data frame. I want a set of all such number with a different value in the column `Ordertype` as my output.

Comment: In both dataframes `OrderNo` "8" corresponds to "d". Are you sure you have given enough information for us to try to help you?

Comment: Yes, I really need help. I have made the changes. Sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: `xxx$orderNo[xxx$Ordertype != yyy$orderType]`?

Comment: `which(xxx$Ordertype != yyy$Ordertype)`

Comment: How can I get a data frame which gives me three columns - "xxx$OrderNo" "xxx$Ordertype" "yyy$Ordertype" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want a data frame that contains differences between two data frames, matched by (and including) `orderNo`. Is that correct?

One possibility is:

```
res <- merge(xxx, yyy, by = "orderNo")
res[res[,2] != res[,3], ]

  orderNo Ordertype.x Ordertype.y
7       7           c           e
```

Using `dplyr` and `anti_join` you can do the following to find differences:

```
library(dplyr)
inner_join(anti_join(xxx, yyy), anti_join(yyy, xxx), by='orderNo')

  orderNo Ordertype.x Ordertype.y
1       7           c           e
```